# Implementing a distributed transaction is it theoretically possible?

Tags: database, xodus

I want to ask a theoretical question.

Is it theoretically possible to implement a distributed transaction for [Xodus Database](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus)?

- If yes, what are the theoretical steps to make it work?
- If not, then what are the reasons why it can't be implemented?